# Gradle task sonarquube fail with 401 error on http://localhost:9000/api/settings/values.protobuf

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, gradle, sonarqube

I am trying to run the sonarqube task. My current configuration was working before I did some refactoring.

Now I only have this error when trying to deploy to sonar :

```
05:35:30.354 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':sonarqube'.
05:35:30.778 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
05:35:30.778 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
05:35:30.778 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
05:35:30.779 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
05:35:30.779 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
05:35:30.779 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
05:35:30.779 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
05:35:37.996 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] keyStore is : 
05:35:37.996 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] keyStore type is : jks
05:35:37.996 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] keyStore provider is : 
05:35:37.996 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] init keystore
05:35:37.997 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] init keymanager of type SunX509
05:35:38.582 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Create : /root/.sonar/cache
05:35:38.583 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
05:35:38.583 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Create : /root/.sonar/cache/_tmp
05:35:38.583 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
05:35:39.016 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Get bootstrap index...
05:35:39.016 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Download: http://sonarqube.service.domain-ovh.consul/batch/index
05:35:39.175 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Get bootstrap completed
05:35:39.176 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Download http://sonarqube.service.domain-ovh.consul/batch/file?name=sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.3.jar to /root/.sonar/cache/_tmp/fileCache4796792494988802521.tmp
05:35:40.778 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
05:35:40.778 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
05:35:40.778 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
05:35:40.779 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
05:35:40.779 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
05:35:40.779 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
05:35:40.779 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
05:35:42.976 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Create isolated classloader...
05:35:42.980 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Start temp cleaning...
05:35:43.044 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Temp cleaning done
05:35:43.045 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Execution getVersion
05:35:43.050 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Execution start
05:35:44.704 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Publish global mode
05:35:44.820 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Load global settings
05:35:44.866 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] GET 401 http://sonarqube.service.domain-ovh.consul/api/settings/values.protobuf | time=38ms
05:35:44.867 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
05:35:44.867 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':sonarqube'
05:35:44.867 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] :sonarqube FAILED
05:35:44.875 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :sonarqube (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 23.022 secs.
05:35:44.875 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationWorkerRegistry] Worker root.212 completed (0 in use)
05:35:44.875 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]] finished, busy: 1 mins 4.856 secs, idle: 0.053 secs
05:35:44.904 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
05:35:44.904 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
05:35:44.904 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
05:35:44.904 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
05:35:44.904 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
05:35:44.904 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller
05:35:44.904 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
05:35:44.904 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
05:35:44.904 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
05:35:44.905 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
05:35:44.905 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
05:35:44.905 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
05:35:44.905 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 1 mins 16.583 secs
05:35:44.914 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for task history cache (/var/jenkins_home/jobs/59.TEST.SONAR.com.domain.api/workspace/.gradle/3.3/taskArtifacts)
05:35:44.914 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache taskArtifacts.bin (/var/jenkins_home/jobs/59.TEST.SONAR.com.domain.api/workspace/.gradle/3.3/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin)
05:35:44.915 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileHashes.bin (/var/jenkins_home/jobs/59.TEST.SONAR.com.domain.api/workspace/.gradle/3.3/taskArtifacts/fileHashes.bin)
05:35:44.915 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileSnapshots.bin (/var/jenkins_home/jobs/59.TEST.SONAR.com.domain.api/workspace/.gradle/3.3/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin)
05:35:44.915 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on task history cache (/var/jenkins_home/jobs/59.TEST.SONAR.com.domain.api/workspace/.gradle/3.3/taskArtifacts).
05:35:44.916 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
05:35:44.917 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 88, disk reads: 44 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.038 secs)
05:35:44.917 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 2 resolution results binary files in 0.001 secs
05:35:44.917 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Plugin Resolution Cache (/root/.gradle/caches/3.3/plugin-resolution) was closed 0 times.
05:35:44.917 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cache directory workerMain (/root/.gradle/caches/3.3/workerMain).
05:35:44.917 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Generated Gradle JARs cache (/root/.gradle/caches/3.3/generated-gradle-jars) was closed 0 times.
05:35:44.917 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.daemon.WorkerDaemonManager] Stopping 0 worker daemon(s).
05:35:44.917 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.daemon.WorkerDaemonManager] Stopped 0 worker daemon(s).
05:35:44.918 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for artifact cache (/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2)
05:35:44.918 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache artifact-at-repository.bin (/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/artifact-at-repository.bin)
05:35:44.918 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-metadata.bin (/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/module-metadata.bin)
05:35:44.918 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache artifact-at-url.bin (/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/artifact-at-url.bin)
05:35:44.918 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-versions.bin (/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/module-versions.bin)
05:35:44.918 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on artifact cache (/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2).
05:35:44.918 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
05:35:54.403 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=5703, address=[acc80858-1052-4e9e-a543-9ead0a717415 port:52278, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Busy, lastBusy=1492832070577, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=3b484f5c-62d4-479c-b8f4-19809333acf1,javaHome=/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_SDK_8u131,daemonRegistryDir=/root/.gradle/daemon,pid=5703,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
05:35:54.403 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished
05:35:54.404 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: connection stop
```

This is how I add the Gradle Sonarqube Plugin to my buildscript classpath: (in my root build.gradle)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        sonarqubeGradlePluginVersion = '2.3'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:${sonarqubeGradlePluginVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'


sonarqube {
  properties {
    property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
    property "sonar.host.url", "${sonar_host_url}"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "${sonar_project_key}"
    property "sonar.projectName", "${sonar_project_key}"
  }
}
```

and in `gradle.properties`:

```
## SonarQube
sonar_host_url=http://sonarqube.service.domain-ovh.consul
sonar_project_key=com.domain.api
```

This error occurred when executing Gradle on Jenkins. I am not using the Jenkins Sonarqube Plugin

What is it about ?

Comment: How do you add the *Gradle Sonarqube Plugin* to your buildscript classpath? Does this error occurr when executing Gradle locally or on Jenkins? Are you using the *Jenkins Sonarqube Plugin*?

Comment: I  have replied to all theses questions and added some configuration

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing SonarQube credentials (login if using token, or login/password) in your project configuration

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.host.url", "${sonar_host_url}"
        property "sonar.login", "${sonar_login}"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "${sonar_project_key}"
        property "sonar.projectName", "${sonar_project_key}"
    }
}
```

and in `gradle.properties`

```
## SonarQube
sonar_host_url=http://sonarqube.service.domain-ovh.consul
sonar.login=*****token*****
sonar_project_key=com.domain.api
```